# Side tab positioned absolute and overflowing window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a tab on the side of the browser window that when clicked uses jquery to slide it in and display it. The problem is that because I have it absolute positioned, it's overflowing the body and I can't seem to get that to stop. When it's pulled in by the jQuery it no longer overflows. Only When it's hidden.

JS:

```
        $(tabs).click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var block = '#block-webform-client-block-12';
        if($(tabs).hasClass("isDown")) {
            $(block).animate({ right: '+=380'}, 500 ),
            //$(block).css({ position: 'absolute' });
            $(tabs).removeClass("isDown");
            $('.block-webform .quote-tab.open').hide();
            $('.block-webform .quote-tab.close').show();
        } else {
            $(block).animate({ right: '-=380' }, 500 )
            //$(block).css({ position: 'fixed'});
            $(tabs).addClass("isDown");
            $('.block-webform .quote-tab.open').show();
            $('.block-webform .quote-tab.close').hide();
        }
        return false;
    });
```

CSS:

```
#block-webform-client-block-12 {
position: absolute;
top: 20%;
right: -380px;
background: $button-color;
padding: 15px;
width: 350px;
color: white;
z-index: 99;
@include zen-grid-container();
.quote-tab {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -46px;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="block-webform-client-block-12" class="block block-webform contextual-links-region last even">
<h2 class="block-title">
  Get a Quote
</h2>
<article class="node-12 node node-webform node-promoted contextual-links-region view-mode-full node-by-viewer clearfix" about="/get-quote" typeof="sioc:Item foaf:Document">
  <div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">
    <div class="field-items">
      <div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded">
        <img src="/sites/domain.com/files/close-quote-tab.png" class="quote-tab close"> <img src="/sites/domain.com/files/open-quote-tab.png" class="quote-tab open">
        <p>
          Fill out this form to request a quote or set up an appointment. For more information, <strong>call 123-456-7890</strong>.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form class="webform-client-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/get-quote" method="post" id="webform-client-form-12" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    ...form_components...
```

Screenshot
[image: broken_absolute]

I want to make it so that when the form is off screen only the tab is showing and you cannot scroll to see the rest of the form

Comment: add `display: none` to the CSS

Comment: This wont work as the tab itself is inside the block that I would need to hide

Answer (score 0):

You'll need `overflow-x: hidden` one way or another.

If you're sure none of your other content will overflow the page width, you can simply set it on the `body` itself.  If not, you'll need some sort of wrapper with `overflow-x: hidden`.

http://jsfiddle.net/aZU3S/1

Comment: This seems to also prevent me from scrolling down vertically

Comment: Sorry, should have pointed that out.  You only want `overflow-x` if you use it on the body.  If you have to use a wrapper and things extend too far vertically as well, you may have to get a bit trickier with your overflow.

Comment: For some reason this does not seem to change anything with the scrolling

Comment: Are you saying `overflow-x: hidden` is preventing you from scrolling vertically?  That should not be the case http://jsfiddle.net/aZU3S/2/

Comment: No, I am able to still scroll vertically and horizontally, as if no change has occurred form applying it. When I apply overflow: hidden. It prevents all scrolling. 

Overflow-x seems to be exactly what I want but it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Is there a live site that is public or can you reproduce this in jsfiddle?

Comment: That link looks perfect to me... which browser are you using.

Comment: hahaha.. Chrome 27 on Mac. It's not letting you scroll to the side to see the form?

Comment: Wait, would it be because of my mac "magic" mouse letting me scroll sideways?

Comment: IE9 and FF21, no horizontal scrollbar.  I don't know much about mac's witchcraft, but maybe.

Comment: Yeah when I view it in a VM i don't see it. Oh apple.. Thanks for checking it out for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the overflow to scroll?

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```